# How to restrict multiple users having same role from accessing other users' data in a Web API when using JWT?

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I have a ASP.NET Core Web API linked to a database, and in the database is a table containing User details and roles. There are 2 roles, Admin and Basic. The desired functionality using JsonWebToken is that user with role Admin should be able to add,edit, select and delete on all entries of the User table, whereas when a user with role Basic logs in, they should only be able to edit, view and delete only their own record. Suppose a user with ID 1 logs in, is there a way to only allow

https://localhost:44372/api/User/**1** to be accessed by User 1 and

https://localhost:44372/api/User/**2**
should be inaccessible to them?

Also the same logic needs to be applied for delete and Update. Can anything that be done?

Comment: Have you tried looking at [Claims-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0#adding-claims-checks) ?

Comment: I second the above - You can easily verify that the logged in user is the same as the user being edited via. Claims, either by username, userid etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do check out the built in Resource-based authorization functionality in ASP.NET Core.

You can read more about it here:

- [Resource-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Alternatively, you add the UserId claim included in the access token and then in the backend database queries include it to make sure you can only access what you are supposed to be able to access.